# C++ question: what is "class UserDefinedType* MemberName;" when declared as a property of a class?

Tags: c++

I would expect the declaration of a user-defined type member variable (a pointer to be specific) to look something like:

```
...
public:
  UserDefinedType* MemberName;
...
```

But I've seen this in a few examples:

```
...
public:
  class UserDefinedType* MemberName;
...
```

Apologies for what I'm sure is an obvious question to answer, I just don't really know what to search for. I've looked at nested classes in C++, but I'm unsure if that's what is happening here. Honestly feels like a somewhat redundant identifier.

Any comments, links, corrections, are appreciated thank you.

Comment: You could use that to avoid a separate forward declaration of the type `UserDefinedType`. Perhaps `UserDefinedType` is not known to the compiler at this point in the file.

Comment: Related to forward declarations: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a forward declaration

```
class UserDefinedType {
}; 
 
class A { 
  public:
     UserDefinedType * member1; // this is ::UserDefinedType
     class UserToBeDefinedType; // forward declaration
     UserToBeDefinedType * member2; // this is A::UserDefinedType
}; 
 
class A::UserToBeDefinedType { // define the class 
};
 
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.member1 = new UserDefinedType;    // OK
    //a.member2 = new UserDefinedType;  // KO
    //a.member1 = new A::UserDefinedType; // KO
    a.member2 = new A::UserToBeDefinedType; // OK
}
```

---

[Run and test the code](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27class+UserDefinedType+%7B%0A%7D%3B+%0A+%0Aclass+A+%7B+%0A++public:%0A+++++UserDefinedType+*+member1%3B+//+this+is+::UserDefinedType%0A+++++class+UserToBeDefinedType%3B%0A+++++UserToBeDefinedType+*+member2%3B+//+this+is+A::UserDefinedType%0A%7D%3B+%0A+%0Aclass+A::UserToBeDefinedType+%7B+%0A%7D%3B%0A+%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++A+a%3B%0A++++a.member1+%3D+new+UserDefinedType%3B++++//+OK%0A++++//a.member2+%3D+new+UserDefinedType%3B++//+KO%0A++++//a.member1+%3D+new+A::UserDefinedType%3B+//+KO%0A++++a.member2+%3D+new+A::UserToBeDefinedType%3B+//+OK%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.633136094674555,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:32.726704701966504,l:%274%27,m:45.18716577540107,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:54.81283422459893,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.366863905325445,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Maybe read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

EDIT: Enhance the quality of example and add link to run code